# Python-Django project that can run both on cloud (gae) and locally without internet connection

Tags: java, python, django, google-app-engine

I am working on a test project using Python on Django Project and will run on GAE. I stumble into a problem when one of the requirement states that the application should have a facility/mechanism of saving data from transactions even when there is no internet connection.

Normally it should work sending data for storage over the net. But, when connection is not available, it should save the data on a local temporary storage. The system should also have the facility to update cloud storage once detected that local storage has latest data. It's like an resolution to address downtime on the end user's side (I mean I believe cloud platforms had their different forms of resolving downtime but how about the down time for end users - no internet connection).

So the application should could work both on the 'cloud' when possible (with strong internet connection) or can also work without connection by saving on local storage. I really need inputs from Google app engine developers out there. Actually I am trying to test this on both Java and Python.

Answer (score 1):

There is no magic here whatsoever. Something that is made to work in the cloud, is not really working out of the box without Internet.

Just to point you to a direction, you will have to do it manually yourself if you want to give to the end user a smooth support when Internet connection is going down. Among other things you will most likely going to use [Web Storage, IndexedDB and Web SQL Database](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/features/storage) to support offline functionality and none of them have anything to do with GAE.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are describing is not related or specific to GAE, your hosting provider or Django. What you need are the means to enable offline capabilities on the client, i.e. your web browser and  to synchronize to your backend, i.e. Django. To do so, you need to get familiar with HTML 5 and you might want to check this out.

- Offline Capabilities: http://diveintohtml5.info/offline.html
- Local Storage: http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html

But none of these is related to GAE as you will see. A nice libarary to support this might be Backbonejs.org

Comment: Thank you guys... I am actually thinking of the html5's abilities to work around these but, I just thought that maybe the gae have something that could (but since I am new to gae, i thought i might some expert advise). Anyways, thank you very much.